# c++ login executes the main code even if the the login is wrong

Tags: c++

i developed a login page using a classes and after i wrote the remaining code in the int main but the is a situation where if the login is wrong the the remaining code still runs .i want a situation where by if the the login from the class is invalid the remaining code should not run

```
cout<<"hey Please Enter your password \n  Username : "; cin>> usernameAttempt;

        if(usernameAttempt == userName)
        {
            cout<<"Password: ";
            cin>>passwordAttempt;
            if(passwordAttempt==password)
            {
                cout<<"congrutulations"<<endl;
            }


        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"error!!!! invalid input"<<endl;
        }
```

it continues to run this from the main even when the login is invalid

```
cout<< "                                          |Hello welcome to daily bakery |                                      "<<endl;
cout<<"______________________________________________________________________________________________________________\n\n"<<endl;

cout<<"Please Enter the number of specific bread ordered\n"<<endl;
```

i expect an output of invalid try again but the actual output is invalid ...then the remaining code runs

Comment: set a flag inside your `passwordAttempt==password` if statement, check the flag before allowing use of the rest of your application.

Comment: Where is the part where you made it say invalid try again?

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming this is some homework or toy project of yours.

You need to provide the entire context to get a complete response, but right now you only print things, but don't change control based on it. You need to either branch on the result, by e.g. returning a `bool` that indicates whether login succeeded or directly exit in your current control flow. The most trivial change you can make is to call `exit(1)` after the print-statement in your else-block(s).

If it isn't a toy project scrap it immediately. For an actual password login there a so many things wrong, e.g.:

- uses equals comparison (opens up to timing attack)
- stores actual password (should be salted hash suitable for password storage)
- storing passwords as string in client-applications doesn't work, because they can just read the .data/.text sections of your program
- hard to write these checks s.t. they aren't trivial to reverse

Answer (score 0):

If your posted code is part of a function, then simply have it return true/false. In your main, the part that should run when the login is successful, should then be part of an if statement. Ex.

```
bool validate() {
    cout << "hey Please Enter your password\nUsername : ";
    cin >> usernameAttempt;
    if(usernameAttempt == userName) {
        cout << "Password: ";
        cin >> passwordAttempt;
        if(passwordAttempt == password) {
            cout << "congratulations\n";
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        cout << "error!!!! invalid input\n";
    }
    return false;
}
…
int main() {
    if ( validate() ) {
        // login successful code
    }
}
```